# Getting a time out of datetime and use for comparison SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have the following issue:

I have Orders table that have [Submit Time] Datetime column. I need to prepare a tabular model where one dimension will be just TimesOfDay (like 01:30:00, 21:00:00 etc.) so I can filter out orders on the basis of the [Submit Time] value.

How can I create another column extracting just the time from [Submit Time] in Tabular model?

Outcome:

User opens a Powerview dashboard and can filter out orders based on TimesOfDay

Comment: CAST([Submit Time] AS TIME)

Comment: I cant use that in VS in tabular model

Comment: Restructure your model.

Comment: I am just thinking now that a simple FORMATfunction in DAX might do the job actually..

Comment: I'd rather go with adding calculated column and passing its value into the model instead of actual date/time.